# When a checkbox is checked, certain data from that row is copied to certain cells on another tab

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a tab labeled Camper Master.  On this tab, new rows are inserted and then sorted by last name. This means that the position of the rows change with each new row.

Tab Label: Camper Master
Columns are:

Last Name (A) | First Name (B) | Check In/Out #1 (C) | Check In/Out #2 (D) | Photo Release (E) | Medical Needs (F) | Notes (G) | Add To Roster (H)

Column H has a Checkbox the rest are free entry text

Function Desired:

- A new row is added to the Camper Master tab.
- All fields, other than the Checkbox in Column H is populated.
- Once the row is added, the sheet will sort by Last Name (Column A).
- A user will check the checkbox (Column H) to the right of a person who needs to be added to the roster.
- An automation will occur when the checkbox is selected and perform the following:

  - Once Checkbox is checked (R* : Column H)
  - The process will navigate to the Last Name (Row * : Column A) and copy the contents
  - The process will navigate to the Roster tab and Paste the Last Name in A2:A5 (merged cells)
  - The process will navigate back to the Camper Master tab and copy the First Name (Row * : Column B)
  - The process will navigate to the Roster tab and Paste the First Name in B2:B5 (merged cells)
  - The process will navigate back to the Camper Master tab and copy the Check In/Out #1 (Row * : Column C)
  - The process will navigate to the Roster tab and Paste the Check In/Out #1 in E2:E3 AND H2:H3
  - The process will navigate back to the Camper Master tab and copy the Check In/Out #2 (Row * : Column D)
  - The process will navigate to the Roster tab and Paste the Check In/Out #2 in E4:E5 AND H4:H5
  - The process will navigate back to the Camper Master tab and copy the Photo Release (Row * : Column E)
  - The process will navigate to the Roster tab and Paste the Photo Release in C7:C10
  - The process will navigate back to the Camper Master tab and copy the Medical Needs (Row * : Column F)
  - The process will navigate to the Roster tab and Paste the Medical Needs in A7:B10
  - The process will navigate back to the Camper Master tab and copy the Notes (Row * : Column G)
  - The process will navigate to the Roster tab and Paste the Notes in D7:H10
  - The process returns to the Camper Master tab and ends, until another checkbox is selected

I can get the copying and pasting back and forth, however, what I cannot figure out is how to have all this contingent on a checkbox tied to the row it is in, which will move up and down the sheet.

Also, the reason I don't do a row copy is because the Roster has an esthetic format for printing which will be on a clipboard.

I really appreciate any help. This is for a Children's Program so it is for a good cause. All my other functions are working as designed, I am just stuck here.

Automation which is tied to a checkbox which is tied to a non-static row. I haven't written anything yet because this is tied to a checkbox. Or in other words, the Checkbox is the first step.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Not to be a smart aleck but this is what I have written so far:                                                                           Sub AddToRoster()
'
' AddToRoster Macro
'


End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand you correctly. Anyway, if the animation below seems match with your expectation, then maybe you can modify the code to meet with your data.

[image]

It use a formula in sheet ROSTER 
`=INDIRECT("'MASTER'!A"&MASTER!$H$1)`
`=INDIRECT("'MASTER'!B"&MASTER!$H$1)`
`=INDIRECT("'MASTER'!C"&MASTER!$H$1)`
and so on, just change the letter, A to G for each merged cell (except for the image).

The formula is to read what row number the location of the checkbox which is checked and from what column the value must be filled.

```
Private Sub cbx002_Click()
If cbx002.Value = True Then cbxChange "cbx002"
End Sub
Private Sub cbx003_Click()
If cbx003.Value = True Then cbxChange "cbx003"
End Sub
Private Sub cbx004_Click()
If cbx004.Value = True Then cbxChange "cbx004"
End Sub
Private Sub cbx005_Click()
If cbx005.Value = True Then cbxChange "cbx005"
End Sub
Private Sub cbx006_Click()
If cbx006.Value = True Then cbxChange "cbx006"
End Sub

Sub cbxChange(nm As String)
Dim ctrl As Object: Dim shp As Object
Dim addr As String
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each ctrl In ActiveSheet.OLEObjects
    If TypeName(ctrl.Object) = "CheckBox" And ctrl.Name <> nm Then
        ctrl.Object.Value = False
    Else
        Range("H1").Value = ctrl.TopLeftCell.Row
    End If
Next

addr = Range("E" & Range("H1").Value).Address
    For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        If shp.TopLeftCell.Address = addr Then
            Sheets("ROSTER").DrawingObjects.Delete
            shp.Copy
            Sheets("ROSTER").Range("C7").PasteSpecial (xlAll)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next shp
    
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The example name each checkbox to cbx002 to cbx006, so change them according to the name of each checkbox in your data. If the checkbox is checked (it's value = true), it call the cbxChange sub.

In cbxChange sub, it uncheck other checkbox which is checked previously, and put the row number on cell H1 sheet MASTER.

Then it create addr variable to get the address of the cell with picture. 
Then it loop to each shape (as shp variable) and check if the looped shp TopLeftCell.Address is = addr then it delete the previous image in sheet ROSTER, copy the image then paste in sheet ROSTER cell C7.

Put all the macro in sheet MASTER module.

If there are so many data in sheet MASTER (hence, so many checkboxes), then maybe you want to consider to combine the code using class module.

If what you mean is to add data on each row where the checkbox is checked ---> for example : a user check the 1st, 2nd and the 5th checkbox ---> expected result in sheet ROSTER something like this : cell A1:H11 is the data of the 1st checkbox, cell A12:H22 is the data from the 2nd checkbox and cell A23:H33 is the data from the 5th checkbox ---> then you can make something like a template, modify the formula by putting each row number in sheet ROSTER, modify the code and have a button to run a macro to give you the expected result.

Sorry if I can't explain it thoroughly, I'm limited in English language.